# What is a way to express 'a sudden need to urinate or defecate'?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, north-american-english

If I have a sudden need to use the restroom, how should I express that? I know there is an expression in British English - **[be caught short](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-caught-taken-short)**.

> to suddenly and unexpectedly need to go to the toilet, especially when it is not convenient for you to do so

But I am looking for its North American equivalent.

Comment: "urgency" -----

Comment: Are you happy with an idiom, or an expression? Why does it have to be a single word? Your BrEng (which I'm unfamiliar with) is not a single word.

Comment: No, not necessarily a single word. An idiom or expression would do.

Comment: Go to the loo..

Comment: @Explorer: I've edited out the 'single word' part from the title, as you said it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: If it's really that urgent then "I gotta go!!!" is about as expressive as you can hope for.

Answer (score 4):

> **[nature’s call](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/nature%E2%80%99s+call) and call of nature**
>
> n. the feeling of a need to go to the toilet. *I think I feel nature’s call coming on.* <sub>(TFD)</sub>

(Don't know how common this is in AmE. I pretty sure it works in InE, though.)

Comment: Common enough in American English—everyone will understand what you mean.

Comment: This doesn't imply the sudden or unexpected need that the OP asked about.

Answer (score 3):

You may ask: *"Can I take a **bathroom break**, please?"*

***Bathroom break*** — [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bathroom_break)

> (informal) A break in a meeting or other organized gathering to allow those in attendance to go to the toilet.

I'm sure it's well-understood in the U.S also. A famous usage example from the POTUS Bush in the middle of an important meeting (UN summit): — [BBC News](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/americas/4249646.stm)

> I think I may need a **bathroom break**? Is this possible?

Comment: The OP uses the expression "rest room" in their question. The OP is asking about  the **urgent** need to visit the (nearest) loo/toilet. I know one, but it's in BrEng! :(

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's correct, but in my experience, usually when someone requests a bathroom break, especially during an important meeting, it obviously is a matter of urgency. Also, I faintly remember some news about George Bush requesting a bathroom break during a UN meeting or something.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Aha, see! "I think I may need a bathroom break? Is this possible?" http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/americas/4249646.stm

Answer (score 2):

***[I need to spend a penny](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spend-a-penny):***

> - polite phrase for to urinate:
>
>   - *If you'll excuse me, I need to spend a penny.*

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: +1. Never heard that one before. Is it still in use?

Comment: It's in use in BrE.

Comment: I was not looking for a word/phrase/idiom to used in a sentence asking for permission. It is to be used in reported speech. Example: I bumped into my Professor the other day and I thought he would wind up soon. However, he kept on talking while I _____ (started experiencing a need to use the restroom).

Comment: Never heard this in American English, so I wouldn't say it's common. Of course, there are hundreds of nonsensical idioms for "use the bathroom", like "I need to talk to a man about a horse." People will probably know what you mean, but mostly because it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Cody This one isn’t even nonsensical: it refers to spending a penny on visiting a public lavatory. The question specifically asks for an American phrase, though, and _spend a penny_ is very British, so I don’t think it’s a very good answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's necessary (or desirable) to be too specific as to the exact activity you will be performing. It's sufficient to say you need to "**use the washroom**" (or bathroom, or restroom). The latter three nouns are more-or-less equivalent in some situations and regions and less so in others, so adapt to whatever is common where you are.

That said, I've seen people excuse themselves from long meetings saying that it was a for a "pee break".

In any case, if the need is of a more serious (as opposed to urgent) nature you can signal your intentions to not return immediately.

Non-native speakers often have somewhat awkward-sounding phrases for this- I've heard "I have to wash my hands" and "I have to make water", for example.

Answer (score 2):

The [Car Talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_Talk) guys liked to use ["see a man about a horse"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/See_a_man_about_a_dog):

> To **see a man about a dog** or **horse** is an English idiom, usually used as
>   a way to say one needs to apologise for one's imminent departure or
>   absence—generally to euphemistically conceal one's true purpose, such
>   as going to use the toilet or going to buy a drink.
>
> The original, non-facetious meaning was probably to place or settle a
>   bet on a racing dog.
>
> (Wikipedia)

Comment: I don't think this implies the sudden or unexpected need that the OP asked about.

Answer (score 0):

*Need to spend a penny* is British, and it's terribly quaint. A more modern British equivalent is:

**[burst](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/burst)** UK *informal*

> I'm bursting to go to the loo!

In American English, if you were to say instead *I'm bursting to go to the rest room*, they should understand you. Otherwise, try:

- “I desperately need to [**relieve**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/relieve) myself”

> polite word for urinate :
>   *He proceeded to relieve himself against a tree*.

Understandable in both dialects, I just checked.

Comment: I considered "bursting" initially, but I let it go. :) https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bursting#bursting__9